# find the limit of one sequence $\lim_{ n \to \infty } \cos(\frac{\pi}{2n + 1})\cos(\frac{2\pi}{2n + 1})...\cos(\frac{n\pi}{2n + 1}) $

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

I want to find the limit of this below ***Sequence***.
the first sentence of this sentence n approaches infinity they approaches to 1 but not same for last sentence. How can we solve it.

$\lim_{ n \to \infty } \cos(\frac{\pi}{2n + 1})\cos(\frac{2\pi}{2n + 1})\cos(\frac{3\pi}{2n + 1})...\cos(\frac{n\pi}{2n + 1}) $

Is it possible to help me?
I'm sorry for bad English.
Thanks.

Comment: As it is, it $\to 0$, since it is of the form $a_n = b_n \cos(\pi n / (2n+1))$ where $|a_n| < 1$

Comment: Use $\prod_{r=1}^n \cos\frac{r\pi}{2n+1} = \frac{1}{2^n}$.

Answer (score 6):

First we prove
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\cos\frac{\pi}{2n + 1}\cos\frac{2\pi}{2n + 1}...\cos\frac{n\pi}{2n + 1}\right)^{1/n}=\frac1{2}
$$
Take the log and we have
\begin{align}
\lim_{ n \to \infty }\ln \cos\frac{\pi}{2n + 1}\cos\frac{2\pi}{2n + 1}...\cos\frac{n\pi}{2n + 1}&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{n}\ln \cos\left(k\cdot \frac{\pi}{2n+1} \right) 
\\
&=\int_{0}^{1} \ln \cos\frac{\pi t}{2} dt 
\\
&=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln{\cos{x}}\:dx
\\
&=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln{\sin{x}}\:dx
\end{align}
The last step is through $y=\pi/2-x$.
Let $I=\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln{\cos{x}}\:dx$. Then
\begin{align}
2I&=\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln{\cos{x}}\:dx+\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln{\sin{x}}\:dx
\\
&=\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln{\sin{x}\cos{x}}\:dx
\\
&=\int_0^{\pi/2}(\ln{\sin{2x}}-\ln{2})\:dx
\\
&=\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln{\sin{2x}}\:dx-\frac{\pi\ln{2}}{2}
\\
&=\frac1{2}\int_0^{\pi}\ln{\sin{x}}\:dx-\frac{\pi\ln{2}}{2}
\\
&=\frac1{2}\left(\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln{\sin{x}}\:dx+\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi}\ln{\sin{x}}\:dx\right)-\frac{\pi\ln{2}}{2}
\\
&=\frac1{2}\left(\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln{\sin{x}}\:dx+\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\ln{\cos{x}}\:dx\right)-\frac{\pi\ln{2}}{2}
\\
&=I-\frac{\pi\ln{2}}{2}
\end{align}
Hence $I=-\dfrac{\pi\ln{2}}{2}$. We conclude
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\cos\frac{\pi}{2n + 1}\cos\frac{2\pi}{2n + 1}...\cos\frac{n\pi}{2n + 1}\right)^{1/n}&=\lim_{n\to \infty}e^{\frac1{n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\ln{\left(\cos\frac{k\pi}{2n+1}\right)}}
\\
&=e^{\frac{2}{\pi}I}=e^{-\ln{2}}
\\
&=\frac1{2}
\end{align}
Thus
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}\cos\frac{\pi}{2n + 1}\cos\frac{2\pi}{2n + 1}...\cos\frac{n\pi}{2n + 1}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac1{2^n}=0
$$
%%

Comment: Thanks for answer. Is it possible to prove that without Integral because my teacher said that we can solve without it too. we will learn it later. Is it possible?

Comment: Another proof is in @zhw post which is simpler. This is the proof that solves more general (harder) question that is normally asked: $\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\cos\frac{\pi}{2n + 1}\cos\frac{2\pi}{2n + 1}...\cos\frac{n\pi}{2n + 1}\right)^{1/n}=\frac1{2}$

Answer (score 4):

Each factor in the product lies between $0$ and $1.$ Thus the product lies between $0$ and the last factor, which is $\cos \pi(n/(2n+1)).$ As $n\to \infty,$ this factor $\to \cos (\pi/2) =0.$ Therefore the product converges to $0.$